# "There's," is only for singular subjects

Tags: plural-forms, contractions

"There's," seems a lazy way of saying, "There're," when the object is plural.

In recent times, two words, February and instrument, have kept their spelling, but newly are allowed to be pronounced as Febuary and insturment.  I have no idea who or where the keeper of this slow legitimization is - dictionaries, or common usages, newly sanctioned, whatever.  [It would be interesting enough, to know that; who or what is the living English language authority?]

What I loathe is people saying, "There's several things ..."  I imagine it's because saying, "There're several things," is so uncomfortable to say.  As those other two words were.  Further, "There're," provokes my spell checker.

I say, a contractor must use, "There're," in spite of it all, and that in plural contexts, "There's," is simply wrong - e.g. There is several things.

Am I right to stick to my guns here?  And, how (much) right?

Comment: This is a thinly disguised rant, perhaps better suited for EL&U. Proof that the misspellings of february and instrument are to be found in dictionaries would be interesting though. I'm not sure we can just take your word for it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd happily vote for it to get migrated to EL&U, that isn't a reason to downvote though when we have that provision.

Comment: @Astralbee I am voting to close for it being a rant and for being primarily opinion-based. That words are not pronounced as they are spelled (or spelt)  are as old as the hills. There are hundreds of words whose letters are omitted, nothing new to see here.

Comment: The comments received, none posted, are very instructional.  My question was clearly one of dictionary VS usage, and of advice navigating the twain.  This seemed to trip up many respondents'  role identifications..

Comment: Sorry for this dual post.  There should be a note that attempting to enter a blank line to clarify text, will instead be taken as a 'return/end of message'.  [paragraph] The following is truth to the best of my knowledge.  The response set to this question was very revealing.  My question was said to be calling for an opinion, even, by one, a thinly veiled rant.  It was not.  This is opinion: your organization is much more self-conscious than material conscious.  The responses certainly were, with one exception, opinion.  Looks like an epidemic, neurotic, opinion-retentive syndrome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked a *controversial question*. This is because technically, you are correct - "*there's*" is a contraction of "there is", and to use it in place of "there are" could not be supported by credible resources. None of the leading dictionaries, such as Cambridge or Websters, suggest that "there's" could be used to mean "there are". The popular grammar checker *Grammarly* highlights a sentence like "*there's two of them*" as a mistake, recommending that it be changed to "*there are two...*". Simply put, a non-native speaker learning to speak English from books on grammar would never be taught to use it this way. However, native English speakers *do* sometimes use it that way, and I'm facing criticism for saying it is 'wrong' to do so.

When native speakers say "there are", there is sometimes a naturally-occurring contraction of these words. Although it seems reasonable that "there're" would be a recognised contraction in written English (after all, "*we're*" is a contraction of 'we are') this is also not found in reliable dictionaries, although I do see it in some less-reliable 'wiki' resources. For that reason, you are unlikely to see it written *unless* the writer is trying to capture the sound of spoken language in their prose. You will often see unofficial contractions (for example, "*'aint*" instead of 'isn't') in written dialogue that is trying to emulate regional dialects, for example.

An important difference between written English and spoken English is that speech is often extemporaneous. A speaker often begins a sentence without knowing precisely how they are going to end it. This is just one reason why certain things that would be considered mistakes in written English are ignored in spoken language, and possibly why you hear this from time to time.

In summary, if you're a professional writer you should expect an editor to pick up on this as a mistake. Otherwise, it isn't a mistake worth worrying about.

Comment: There's nothing wrong or ungrammatical in saying "there's" when the first word that follows is singular:  *In my village there's a bridge, a footpath and a fountain made of brass".

Comment: @Mari-LouA You've cited an example where it is commonly accepted, but I could reel off examples where it is clearly an error. I avoided getting into where it is right and wrong because the OP seems aware of that and is only interested in why it is wrongly used. Very unfair of you to abuse the voting system to take out your issues with the question on my answer.

Comment: I downvoted because I disagreed with the answer: "You're quite right about everything" and "It is wrongly used by many native speakers when they should say 'there are'." Is that abusing the system? But this is why we have upvotes and downvotes. I downvoted and also explained why. Why was that unfair? I'm not stopping anyone else from upvoting the answer.

Comment: If many native speakers say it (and they do) then it is not "wrong". Language is what it is, not what somebody thinks it should be.

Comment: @ColinFine So, would you be prepared to say in an answer that it is "correct"? And could you cite credible references to support that? I have not said "it's wrong, don't use it"... I've hopefully got across that it is technically wrong but people *do* use it.

Comment: Ngram, its results are taken from published works. The phrase: ["There's several“](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27s+several&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20%27s%20several%3B%2Cc0) is clearly on the rise.  Press "enter" to see the results, I have no idea why I can see it on my computer but not when I click on the link here.

Comment: And as native speakers and contributors should be aware of, the results are taken from written works. Very very often what is perfectly permissible in speech is frowned on in **formal writing**. Still, here's (?) the results https://www.google.com/search?q=%22there%27s%20several%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2015,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en  Is every writer wrong?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, I've updated my answer. I'd like to think it will keep you happy but I always prefer to be correct than popular and certainly not chasing your upvote. I'm of the opinion that English language learners come here with questions to learn the *right* way. I can't in good conscience answer this by saying there isn't an error. It is more complex than that. I thought I'd covered that well, but hopefully now I've covered it more thoroughly.

Comment: I'll retract the downvote. But your answer is still implying saying "In my village there's a bridge, a footpath and a stream” is "wrong". On contraire I find "There are a bridge, a path, a church etc. to sound quite stilted. Maybe others will disagree. Learners must be made aware that native speakers don't need to learn English from Raymond Murphy and Michael Swan etc.

Comment: @Astralbee: I don't use "correct/incorrect", which are judgjments about etiquette and have little to do with language. I also don't believe in "technically wrong". If a significant number of people use a construction, then it is grammatical. If somebody has a grammar which does not allow it, then their grammar is (at best) incomplete.